# Force Close when opening app after pressing home button

Tags: android

I have a game which has surfaceview and running on a thread.
if I press HOME button when the game's playing and then I open the game again through the icon, I get a force close. what's the problem might be?

Comment: Maybe android does not approve of your game. I dont know. Lets see the logs to see what android is complaining about ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you start your `Thread` by using `thread.start()` in the `surfaceCreated` callback? If so, there will always be an error if you're not using a member variable that contains a check if your game has been started.

You need to "pause" your `Thread` in the `surfaceDestroyed` callback using `wait()` command so it doesn't reiterate your game code during pause. Next time you're starting your application (for the first time or maybe second time) you need to `start()` it or `notify()` it (after pausing) depending on the circumstances.

At last, always always post code. That will engage people to answer the question properly and correct.

Comment: @Gaurav: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318847/android-crash-when-app-is-closed-and-reopened/5318902#5318902